# QtWebEngine - procedure not found

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtwebengine

I have a simple C++ (non Qt Quick) application (that does not use .pro mechanism) built against the official Qt 5.4.2 x64 build (with openGL support).
As soon as I use the QWebEngineView object in my application, it fails to load with a message "Specified procedure could not be found".

With the help of gflags, it seems it fails to find the following demangled procedure:

```
public: __cdecl QOpenGLWidget::QOpenGLWidget(class QWidget * __ptr64,class QFlags<enum Qt::WindowType>) __ptr64
```

I am not sure to understand why this cannot be found, I have put for the sake of testing all the dlls in Qt_DIR\bin next to the application, and all the plug-ins.
The preprocessor list I use to build my app are as follow:

```
WIN32;_DEBUG;_WINDOWS;_USRDLL;WIN64;QT_WEBENGINEWIDGETS_LIB;QT_WEBENGINE_LIB;QT_QUICK_LIB;QT_PRINTSUPPORT_LIB;QT_WIDGETS_LIB;QT_GUI_LIB;QT_QML_LIB;QT_NETWORK_LIB;QT_UITOOLS_LIB;QT_CORE_LIB;WIN32PROJECT5_EXPORTS;PLUGIN_VENDOR_NAME="$(VendorName)";PLUGIN_VERSION="$(PluginVersion)";PLUGIN_NAME="$(PluginName)";%(PreprocessorDefinitions)
```

And the input libraries:

```
Qt5Cored.lib;Qt5Guid.lib;Qt5Widgetsd.lib;Qt5WebKitd.lib;Qt5WebKitWidgetsd.lib;Qt5WebEngineWidgetsd.lib;Qt5WebEngined.lib;Qt5OpenGLExtensionsd.lib;Qt5OpenGLd.lib;Qt5Networkd.lib;Qt5Xmld.lib;D:\NotBackedUp\Tools\Qt\5.4\msvc2013_64_opengl\lib\qtmaind.lib;shell32.lib;Qt5Quickd.lib;Qt5PrintSupportd.lib;Qt5Qmld.lib;Qt5UiToolsd.lib;glu32.lib;opengl32.lib;gdi32.lib;user32.lib;o2d.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)
```

I wanted to try a simple example in Qt Creator 3.6.1 but it complains: Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webenginewidgets

The browser.exe example runs fine (built with visual studio)

Do you have any idea of what is wrong?
PS: I am on windows 8.1.

Comment: Ultimately, what I want is to login to a google back end using OAuth 2. SO i need to show a browser that will ask the user to login in order to retrieve the access token. if you know alternate way of doing this in Qt, i am open :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the procedure not found, my dll is a plug-in of a Qt application that is not built with opengl support. Only my dll is built with opengl support.
When initializing the plug-in, the application uses its own dlls rather the mine... and therefore fails to have any opengl support for the web engine.

For Qt Creator, it selected automatically a wrong kit. I had to create a new kit which maps to the correct Qt binaries (with opengl support): follow this: http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-configuring-projects.html.

Hope it will help someone